# Rails 4 SQL Update taking too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-update

My `User` table has *5* records. I have a method which updates a user's `auth_token`:

```
   def reset_auth_token
     update_column(:auth_token, generate_token)
   end
```

and the `generate_token` method:

```
  def generate_token
    token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(23)
    User.exists?(auth_token: token) ? generate_token : token
  end
```

(I am using update_column because as the token is being generated server-side I am skipping validations, there are no callbacks, and I don't need the user updated_at attribute to change)

An example SQL generated by this method is

```
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = 'XA0syuJg0PGHrAHW78_S3KLGv71_kqY' LIMIT 1
  SQL (6.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "auth_token" = 'XA0syuJg0PGHrAHW78_S3KLGv71_kqY' WHERE "users"."id" = 3
```

6.3ms!!! With only 5 records. I have already checked to make sure there are no triggers enabled for this database table and I added an index on the `auth_token` attribute (since I frequently check whether users exist based on that attribute). What are other possible explanations for why the update is taking so long?

UPDATE

As suggested I ran an EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE users SET auth_token = 'foo' WHERE id = '1';

                                   QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on users  (cost=0.14..8.15 rows=1 width=4167)
   ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.14..8.15 rows=1 width=4167)
         Index Cond: (id = 1)
(3 rows)
```

Comment: `explain (buffers, analyze)` the query. My first thought is severe table bloat. Any chance you've gone and turned off autovacuum in PostgreSQL or otherwise messed with it? My other thought is that some other session held a lock on it at the time you first issued the update.

Comment: @CraigRinger i updated my answer to show the result of the explain. I haven't touched Postgres and even dropped my database and recreated it to make sure nothing else had happened. I don't understand the "some other session held a lock on it at the time you first issued the update" part?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing the `D` of `ACID`.  The transaction log has to reach a specific spot on disk, and it takes about that long for a 10K rpm disk to make a rotation.

If your users just can't possibly wait for one hundredth of a second, you can try turning off synchronous_commit for that transaction.

Comment: This is on the login page of my app. I set up a custom passwordless login so the user just enters their username, a new unique token link is generated and then emailed to them so they can click it and be logged in. It is important in this case for it to work quickly. I just read the docs 'turning synchronous_commit off can be a useful alternative when performance is more important than exact certainty about the durability of a transaction.',is it safe in this situation to turn that off since the token in the email must match with the token stored in the db?

Comment: It is import that it work in less 6 ms?  I am finding that hard to believe.  But in any event, email inherently is not reliable.  There are all kinds of reasons an email won't go through, and then they would just need to request another token (which your system needs to allow).  You are introducing a very small possibility that they would get an email, and then find it didn't work because the database forget it sent it.  But, same solution, they need to try again, so it doesn't seem like a big risk.